# MySQL select all pinned and some other flagged record to reach limit

Tags: mysql

I have a "products" table where are stored all the store products, some of them are flagged with "hp" flag and some also with "hppin" flag

I need 2 flags because i pick 10 random products from all of the "hp" flagged ( they could 100 or more ) but I need to get all the pinned one.

The pinned need to be always inside the 10 selected products

I need 10 records = all "hppin" flag + random "hp" flag

example table

```
PRODUCTS
| id | name   | hppin | hp |
| 1  | prod1  | y     | y  |
| 2  | prod2  | n     | y  |
| 3  | prod3  | y     | y  |
| 4  | prod4  | n     | y  |
| 5  | prod5  | n     | n  |
| 6  | prod6  | y     | y  |
| 7  | prod7  | n     | y  |
| 8  | prod8  | n     | y  |
| 9  | prod9  | n     | y  |
| 10 | prod10 | n     | y  |
| 11 | prod11 | n     | y  |
| 12 | prod12 | n     | y  |
| 13 | prod13 | n     | y  |
| 14 | prod14 | n     | n  |
| 15 | prod15 | n     | y  |
```

I could solve this with 2 query but I would like to know if is possible 
to do it just in one query.

The result should be record 1,3,6 + 7 random record with hp = y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase your query using a union between the two sets of data which you want to obtain.  The first half of the below union retrives `hppin` yes records.  The second half obtains `hp` yes records.  We then apply a limit of 10 records using an ordering which gives preference to the `hppin` matches first.  The `hp` records would only enter the result set if there were fewer than 10 `hppin` records, which would be the case for your sample data.

```
SELECT id, name, hppin, hp, 1 AS position
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE hppin = 'y'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, hppin, hp, 2
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE hp = 'y'
ORDER BY
    position, RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: in not necessary position after 2? SELECT id, name, hppin, hp, 2 AS position

Comment: @al404IT No...aliases in any query of a union will be ignored except for the first query.